# jqPlot. Show a subset of a series

Tags: jqplot

I have an array, `fullset(24)`, containing plot data for the last 24h, by the hour. This array i feed to jqPlot to create a bar graph. Works fine. But I want to show only a subset of the data, say the business hours (8-17). I do this, rather clumsily, by creating a new array containing a subset and some additional trickery with the ticks, like so:

```
var ticks = [];
var subset = [];
for (i = 8; i < 17; i++)
{
    subset[i - 8] = fullset[i][1];
    ticks.push(sprintf("%d-%d", i, i + 1));
}
```

But is there a better way? Is it possible to somehow tell jqPlot to show only a subset of the full set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the axes settings, I have set a minimum and maximum, but not sure if this will do the same as you are looking for.

```
axes: {
    xaxis: {
        min:8,
        max:16,
    },
},
```

Comment: Tnx Steven, Thing is, I can't get min/max to work properly. But after your suggestion I've done some more trial&error and the problem seems to be min/max together with the CategoryAxisRenderer; with this renderer min/max does nothing it seems.